# update a table rows, without triggering on update for a column on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `trainer_table` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `trainer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
) ;
```

I need to update all trainer_id's where user_id is higher than XX to YY, without changing created_date values!!! Which gets triggered on update ....
they should keep their previous values

How do I do write such query in sql ?

Comment: When DATETIME/TIMESTAMP column is updated in a query explicitly then `ON UPDATE` is not applied. Even when it is set to NULL (rather than autoincrement).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update trainer_table 
set trainer_id = 1234, created_date = created_date 
where user_id > 1234 and id < 3000;
```

I think this should do what you're asking. It should do the update AND keep the original value for created_date. This differs from the other response that neglects that detail.

Alternatively you can change the table definition so it's only

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and not on Update. It appears as though the table was defined this way in error.

Comment: I am running a one time scripts to fix some bugs imputs ,... table is ok, this function is being used during operation of backend

Comment: I would argue that it would be better to have a modified_date column, which would update as the current created_date does. It's counter-intuitive to have the created_date _change_ on modifications.